# Spring init and destroy methods

Tags: spring, methods, init, destroy

```
package com.idol;

public class Auditorium {       
Auditorium(){
}  
public void turnOnLights() {  
    System.out.println("Lights are turned on"); 
}  
public void turnOffLights(){  
    System.out.println("Lights are turned off");
}
```

}

For xml context I have:

```
 <bean id="Auditorium" class="com.idol.Auditorium" init-method="turnOnLights" destroy-method="turnOffLights"/>
```

Testing:

```
ApplicationContext auditorium =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContextVer6.xml"); 

auditorium.getBean("Auditorium");
```

I get:

**Does only print "Lights are turned on" and doesn't print "Lights are turned off". I though that before destroying the bean it should invoke the destroy-method too, what am I missing or not getting? (I have no errors in log, just in case)**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
final ConfigurableApplicationContext auditorium =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContextVer6.xml");
auditorium.getBean("Auditorium");
auditorium.close(); // thx Nathan

// auditorium.refresh() will also turn the lights off
// before turning them on again
```

Comment: @Nathan. Grr, yes, that would have been perfect. Write it as an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: This example from "Spring in action". Bug in the book)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot observe destroy method working, because beans are available in Spring context all the time. When you close/destroy your application context, then all beans instantiated within it should be destroyed. Take a look at the `close()` and `destroy()` methods at the `org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext` class.